# Have some questions about setting up a VPN to my private cloud servers

Tags: vpn, ipsec, pptp, l2tp, sstp

#### TLDR:

I wish to VPN to our cloud servers. Is there any free VPN server software that runs on W2K8?

No, I don't want to :

1. Download 3rd party software for the -clients- (We want to use the built in VPN client software in Windows 7)
2. Use the VPN service in our Cisco firewall. (see point 1)

---

#### Detailed Question

I've got a number of Virtual Servers running at a pretty big Cloud provider. They are all running Windows 2008 R2. I have a CISCO ASA firewall in front of them. Currently, I've got all ports blocked except 80/443/21/3386 (for Remote Desktop).

I asked to have a VPN enabled on the firewall and they said it's easy to do BUT I need to use the 3rd party Cisco software. Now, I don't want to get into a debate about it .. but we don't want to install anything extra on our -client- computers.

We all use Windows 7 and we love using the built in VPN client to connect to other private LANS we have setup in other locations.

So i'm wondering what options I have to create a VPN tunnel to our private cloud LAN?

All our cloud servers are part of WORKGROUP, so there's no Active Directory .. nor do we want to install all that.

Secondly, we know we can open up a firewall port - so any ports for starting a VPN is fine!

Lastly, I was thinking of just using one of the existing servers as the VPN server (and using the Windows VPN software) .. but I'm not sure this is a good thing?

Remember -> we just want to use the baked in VPN software in Windows 7 .. which is PPTP or SSTP or L2TP/IPSEC. I would -LOVE- to use some free OSS software (on the -Server-)

For usernames/passwords? We'd probably just have one account .. like U:Hithere P:whatever..
so we don't need any hardcore account management, like Active Directory, etc.

So does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install RRAS (part of windows) on any of your cloud systems. Tell them to change their firewall accordingly (allow PPTP control and IP subprotocol 47 = GRE for PPTP to pass through). FInished.

I am all with you - it sucks having to install third party software for a VPN while Windows hasa decent client on board.

Comment: Fraking Awesome! I didn't know if i needed Active Directory for that (RRAS). So .. I install RRAS .. ok. fine. But what about user accounts? Do i just make a new user account on that windows box (which would only exist on that box, of course) and then use that for credentials? (we currently have RRAS + PPTP installed at the office for VPN .. but the office has AD .. so we use an AD account for authorization). Thoughts?

Comment: Well, seriously, the moment you ahve more than 2-3 machines it is always a good idea to have AD anyway. If you do not ant that, do what you think is best for your organization. I use AD for user logins, and local accounts on the router for site/site links.